# Writing an If condition within a Loop in SPSS

Tags: spss

I want to have a if condition within a loop. That is As long as id < 10, 
check if  Modc_initial is equal to MODC, if true then set d = 12

This is the code I tried bit not working, can anyone please help.

> LOOP if (id LT 10)
>
> IF(Modc_initial EQ MODC))
>
> COMPUTE d = 12.
>
> END LOOP.
>
> EXECUTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a one line conditional of the form `IF (condition) d = 12.` or a multiple line `DO IF`. Below I provide an example of `DO IF` adapted to your syntax.

```
data list free / id MODC Modc_initial.
begin data
1 3 3
2 3 5
12 1 1
end data.

LOOP if (id LT 10).
DO IF (Modc_initial EQ MODC).
  COMPUTE d = 12.
END IF.
END LOOP IF (d = 12).
EXECUTE.
```

Note you had a period missing in your original syntax on the initial `LOOP`. I also added an end loop condition, otherwise the code as written would just go until the maximum set number of loops per your system.

Comment: I modified my code to 

`LOOP if (id LT 10).`
`DO IF (Modc_initial EQ MODC).`
`COMPUTE d = 12.`
`END IF.`
`END LOOP if (id EQ 10).`
`EXECUTE.`

But I get the error "Execution of a loop was terminated after MXLOOPS trips. The value of MXLOOPS can be displayed with the SHOW command and changed with the SET command."

Why does this occur, should the loop just run 9 times ? i.e: id: 1 - 9

Comment: @learn_code, looking over my code mine should have received a similar error for the second case. Look in the help section on looping, it sounds like you want something like `LOOP #i = 1 to 9` as opposed to a conditional loop that goes until the end condition.